# Azure AD returns unusable access_token

Tags: azure, oauth

I'm trying to get the access token from the Azure AD, which I'm using as an OAuth identity provider.
I successfully received an authorization code from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize endpoint, and trying to get an access_token. The request has following parameters:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token, Method=POST

grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=<GUID>
&code=<CODE RECEIVED ON THE PREVIOUS STEP>
&redirect_uri=<...>
&client_secret=<SECRET>
```

I'm receiving the following response:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3599",
  "ext_expires_in": "0",
  "expires_on": "1506527801",
  "access_token": "AQABAA...Sc0YMuMr73WQyjzuyAA",
  "refresh_token": "AQABAAAAAAABlDrqfEFlSaui6...xin-iAA",
  "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1...HjgO0A"
}
```

When I'm trying to use the access_token, result always **401 error (Unauthorized)**. id_token looks like a normal JWT token and can be decoded. But access_token and refresh_token are not, looks like they are Base64 encoded values of JWT tokens.

What can cause the 401 error? All requests performed from the same domain. The application is registered with Azure using **app.dev.microsoft.portal**

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by lack of the  "resource" property, which I had to set to the App ID of an application I wanted to get access:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token, Method=POST

grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=<GUID>
&code=<CODE RECEIVED ON THE PREVIOUS STEP>
&redirect_uri=<...>
&resource=a1fc97d5-...-fa8763202a29
&client_secret=<SECRET>
```

After setting the proper permissions in the client app, I got the proper JWT token.